# Самопроизвольный фокус на TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

У меня есть простенький экран, на котором 2 элемента `TextBox` и один `Button`. Обработчик события `Button` начинается со следующих строк:

```
    private async void ForgotButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Button).IsEnabled = false;
```

Проблема в том, что при клике по кнопке, первый `TextBox` самовольно получает на себя фокус, выскакивает экранная клавиатура, мигает курсор. Я не понимаю почему это происходит, ведь я не кликал по нему.
Методом "*научного тыка*" установлено, что именно из-за этой строки появляется проблема.
Вот маленькая демонстрация того, что происходит на экране:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проиcходит это потому, что если элемент задизейблен, то на нем не может быть фокуса, поэтому система переключает фокус на следующий элемент по порядку -- им как раз оказывается текстбокс.

Поскольку в Винфоне нет возможности обходить контролы аналогично нажатию кнопки <kbd>Tab</kbd>, то можете попробовать обоим текстбоксам поставить свойство `IsTabStop=False`.

Comment: Это действительно помогло.

Comment: @Олег ну здорово.